# How to find who is connected to my computer from MAC address?

Tags: port, mac-address, netstat

When I type in the command `netstat -an` into `cmd`, I get information that one of my ports is opened from some MAC address. My qestion is how to close that port and how to find from the MAC address what ip the other computer has?

I get this output:

```
UDP    [fe80::b970:58f1:a42a:a333%11]:1900  *:*
UDP    [fe80::b970:58f1:a42a:a333%11]:50524  *:*
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your output, I don't think those are MAC addresses.  Rather they are IPv6 addresses.  Also, I think the carriage returns got mangled in your question.  I don't think that it is showing any computers connected, rather just that you have process(es) listening on those ports.

To find out what Windows process is involved, you can do a `netstat -anb` (you may have to do this with Administrator priviledges).

Port 1900 is used for the ssdp protocol.  You could turn this off by disabling the `SSDP Discovery` service.

I'm not sure what corresponds to port 50524, but on my system, that same `SSDP Discovery` service is listening on a number of high numbered ports... it may be the same for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `netstat -b`, you can see the applications that have the specific ports listening. You can't (to the best of my knowledge) close ports on demand, only terminate the processes that are accepting the connections.

Also, I think you're confusing MAC addresses with IPv6 addresses. `fe80::b970:58f1:a42a:a333` is **not** a MAC address; it's an IPv6 address. Problem solved; you've got the IP.

<sub>(Information below this line is irrelevant if you don't have a MAC address)</sub>

---

Furthermore, even if you knew the MAC address, I don't know if there is a RARP (Reverse Address Resolution Protocol) for Windows. I know there used to be `rarpd` for Linux, but RARP support was removed version 2.3 of the kernel. You could always fire up WireShark or something similar if you're on a wireless connection or connected to a hub (not a switch) and check the destination addresses of the frames.